# How can I get the frame positions of subviews in Apple's UITableView styles?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to make a cell that looks just like Apple's UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, except the textLabel is a UITextView (so it can be edited). I just set the textLabel to " " (so that the detailTextView is in the right place) and park a UITextView on top of it. So far, so good. It's working except that I can't quite get my UITextView to line up with the other textLabels of the other cells. I'm a tad off (in more ways than one...).

So that got me wondering: is there a way to get the frame of the various bits of a UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cell? The obvious (or seemingly-obvious) way does't work. `cell.textLabel.frame` returns nil, and if you print it, it shows (0, 0, 0, 0) for its frame. Maybe there's another way.

I realize I could hardcode it, but I'm still guessing what those dimensions might be. Programmatically would be nicer... I think.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

A view's frame isn't valid if the view's transform is not the identity transform. I haven't tried it, but you might be able to duplicate the positions of the elements this way:

1. store the cell's transform
2. set the cell's transform to CGAffineTransformIdentity
3. get the frames of the elements
4. set your own elements with the same frames
5. apply the original transform to your cell

It'd be interesting to know if that works -- please post back if you have good luck.

Comment: Before I went to the trouble of doing what you suggest, I thought I'd try to log the transform of the cell or even of its contentView to see if it's not the identity transform. (I don't know enough to know one way or 'tother, so some experimentation sounded reasonable.) But having never dealt with a transform, I'm not even sure what to do to log such a beast. Doing this `NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView.transform);` for anything I just mentioned leads to a crash (strangely, without complaint in the console). Got any suggestions?

Comment: OK, now I know that you don't use "%@" to log a transform, seeing as how transforms are structs 'n' all... But what I end up with if I do `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(cell.contentView.transform));` is `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`, which is the same thing I get when I do `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformIdentity));`. I.e., the cell, all the views within, and even the table all report back the identity transform. So if that's right and you're right, then I should have some valid frames to work with here. Anybody else got any thoughts on this?

Comment: By the way, I ended up hardcoding it... ick.